# SQL Binary occurrence column if user played

Tags: mysql, sql

I have data in the format

```
|user_id|week_id|betId|
|1|1|...|
|1|1|...|
|1|3|...|
|2|2|...|
|2|3|...|
```

These are bet slips where a user can place many bets for each game week. I want to convert this data so that I have a binary column that indicates for each week if a user placed any bets, so given my example, it would be:

```
|week_id|user_id|did_play|
|1|1|1|
|1|2|0|
|2|1|0|
|2|2|1|
|3|1|1|
|3|2|1|
```

Can someone please explain what the SQL query for this would look like

I have currently managed to get the count for each user for each game week using:

```
SELECT user_id, week_id, count(user_id)
FROM game_slips 
GROUP by week_id, user_id
```

I just want to turn the count into a binary column for played/didn't

Comment: What have you tried? Show us your current query attempt.

Comment: I am not sure how to get there, I can get the count for each user for each game week using:

SELECT user_id, round_id, count(user_id)
FROM game_slips 
GROUP by round_id, user_id

Answer (score 0):

You can generate all the rows using a `cross join` and then convert to a boolean:

```
select u.userId, w.weekId, (count(t.userId) > 0) as did_play
from (select distinct userId from t) u cross join
     (select distinct weekId from t) w left join
     t
     on t.userId = u.userId and t.weekId = u.weekId
group by  u.userId, w.weekId
```